# CI_Unit with non-CI_Controller class

Tags: php, codeigniter, inheritance, phpunit

I recently installed the [CI_UNIT](https://bitbucket.org/kenjis/my-ciunit) test environment for my ci application. The preinstalled tests ran as they should but when I tried to test one of my controllers, it crashed at the line

```
$this->CI = set_controller('...');
```

of the controller test class without throwing an error. I found out, that it depends on the class from which I inherit the controller. In my current application I have three levels of inheritance.

- The built in `CI_Controller`
- A class that extends `CI_Controller` and which provides functions that are specific for any kind of controller of this application: The `APP_Controller`.
- Some classes that extend the `APP_Controller` and where one of these, in this case provides functions only interesting for the REST API of the application.

The CI_UNIT however seems to work if and only if the controller directly inherits from CI_Controller. How can I get around this?